# How do I enable remote debugging on the Kindle Silk browser?

Tags: kindle-fire, amazon-silk

I'm trying to use remote debugging through Chrome DevTools for Kindle's Silk Browser. I followed the instructions on their documentation, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/silk/latest/developerguide/remote-debugging.html , but typing "about:developer" doesn't appear to be working. Does anyone have any advice on how I might enable that?

Thanks for your help!

Edit: This is the Kindle Fire HD 7" (3rd Gen).